# ASPNet MVC - in a controller method, return either a list of strings or redirect to Different page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to practice DRY (don't-repeat-yourself) fundamentals and have noticed that I have a lot of this contruct in my controller, where a user hits and endpoint and might not have provided some info I need.

```
public ActionResult doSomething(string jsonArray){
    List<string> deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jsonArray);
    if (deserializedJson.Count == 0){
        TempData["Error"] = "You must select one or items for this type of request";
        return Redirect("Index");
    }

    //business as usual stuff here

}
```

I perform client side validation so we *shouldn't* end up here, but I also like to check for values before proceeding in my controller too.  However, this exact five lines is everywhere so I thought it would be nice to make this into a private method and use it like a guard clause.

```
private List<string> getJson(string jsonArray){
    List<string> deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jsonArray);
    if (deserializedJson.Count == 0){
        TempData["Error"] = "You must select one or items for this type of request";
        return Redirect("Index");
    }
    return deserializedJson;
}
```

The desire is to have the guard clause load the TempData for me if we're off the happy path and direct the use back to the Index where logic in my View would render the error message.

However I can't seem to figure out how to make this method do the double-duty of giving me back a list of strings if all is well, and if not, then redirect the user.

Is merging these two functions a bad idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I got right what you need, but I guess you want to validate the input parameter for controller's methods. There are two ways:

1. override *OnActionExecuting* method of the controller:

```
        private List<string> getJson(string jsonArray)
        {
            List<string> deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jsonArray);
            return deserializedJson;
        }

        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("jsonArray"))
            {
                List<string> deserializedJson = getJson((string)filterContext.ActionParameters["jsonArray"]);
                if (deserializedJson.Count == 0)
                {
                    filterContext.Controller.TempData["Error"] = "You must select one or items for this type of request";
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("Index");
                }
            }
        }
        public ActionResult doSomething(string jsonArray)
        {
           List<string> deserializedJson = getJson(jsonArray);
          //business as usual stuff here

         }
```

2. create a filter and apply it to each method:

```
    [CheckArray]
    public ActionResult doSomething(string jsonArray)
    {
        List<string> deserializedJson = getJson(jsonArray);
       //business as usual stuff here

    }
    public class CheckArrayAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
       public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       {
          List<string> deserializedJson = getJson((string)filterContext.ActionParameters["jsonArray"]);
         if (deserializedJson.Count == 0)
          {
             filterContext.Controller.TempData["Error"] = "You must select one or items for this type of request";
             filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"], action = "Index" }));
           }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Very clean approaches to use. The first is nice because you can simply create a controller with that method and then inherit from it to apply as needed, the second is nice because if you want to you can globally apply it.

Comment: Option 2 is a perfect fit.  Would option 1 apply that check to every method in the controller?  If so, what if a method didn't take the `jsonArray` param?

Comment: You are correct @FoxDeploy, it would be called for each action. Condition `if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("jsonArray"))` checks if an action has `jsonArray` parameter.